# What techniques can I use for shooting vertically from a height of 12 feet?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, technique, shooting-technique, studio, studio-setup

I need to setup a still life shot over a horizontal area (on a studio floor) and shoot from above, most likely using a ladder at a height of approximately 12 feet. For safety and convenience I would ideally like to lock off the camera in an appropriate mount and tether it to my computer at ground level, allowing me to arrange and adjust the image while shooting. I have experience with tethered shooting so am specifically interested in techniques for shooting vertically from this height.

Can anyone offer advice on:

- The most appropriate mount systems for locking a camera at this height?
- Best practises or alternatives for this shooting method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this from a lower height using a boom stand with an umbrella bracket and the appropriate stud mounted in the camera tripod socket. To reach 12 feet you would most likely need to place the boom on a large table or other platform. Best practices: lots (and lots) of sandbags and counterweights to keep things from tipping over, and tape down all your cables to prevent trips and falls.